# Trying to add data at the bottom of a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to gather a data range daily and place it at the bottom of the same sheet, adding a new row for each day, but my code just keeps putting the data over the top of the next line rather than keeping the old one and putting it on the next line down:

```
function recordHistory() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("RECEIPT TRACKER");
 var sh = ss.insertRowAfter(1);
 var source = sheet.getRange("b33:n33");
 var freeze = sh.getRange("b33:n33");
 var values = source.getValues();
 values[0][0] = new Date();
 sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please elaborate a bit? I.e. it's not clear what your question is. Does the code you've posted work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: the code i have just keeps putting the data over the top of the next line rather than keeping the old one and putting it on the next line down.  i am trying to track each day

Comment: Please add this to your question. A question should be comprehensible without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear but from looking at your code I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("RECEIPT TRACKER"); 
  var source = sheet.getRange("b33:n33").getValues(); // Get the values in Row 33 cols B:N
  source[0].splice(0,0,new Date); // Insert a date object at the start of array
  sheet.appendRow(source[0]); // Append a new row at the bottom of the data range with the values from above 
};
```

If this is not correct then please provide a before and after screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.